# send udp broadcast via bash

Tags: linux, echo, socat

I try to send a udp broadcast with 2 (FF 01) bytes over bash, but in my network sniffer I notice it's 3 bytes. `FF 01 0A` where does the line break come from and how can i prevent it?

```
echo -e '\xFF\x01' | socat - udp-datagram:255.255.255.255:1500,bind=:6666,broadcast,reuseaddr
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `-n` to your `echo` or using `printf`

```
$ echo -e '\xFF\x01' | xxd -p
ff010a
$ echo -en '\xFF\x01' | xxd -p
ff01
$ printf '\xFF\x01' | xxd -p
ff01
```

As I think you realize, `0A` is the newline character.  See also: https://www.asciitable.com/